# Grouped UITableView with Shadow and Corner Radius?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I was wondering how one might go about creating a grouped UITableView with sections that have a drop shadow and rounded corners. Also, the section header is selectable, so when the user clicks the header the cells in that section should collapse; therefore, the shadow and rounded corners will need to change to the new size of the section, just the header. Does anybody know how to do what I am talking about? I have attached a UI mockup for reference as well as some code.

Here is a UI Mockup of what I wish to design:
[image: UI Design Mockup]

This is the code I have to set up the tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {
        return nil
    } else if settings[section - 1].isEmpty == false {
        let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! HeaderTableViewCell

        let settingCategories = ["Account", "Notifications", "Personalized Feed", "Color Theme"]

        headerView.settingCategoryTitle.text = settingCategories[section - 1]

        let totalCellHeight = CGFloat(settings[section - 1].count * 63)
        let height = headerView.frame.height + totalCellHeight

        print("Needed Height: \(height)")

        headerView.clipsToBounds = false
        headerView.headerBackground.frame.size.height = height



        print("HeaderView Height: \(headerView.headerBackground.frame.size.height)")

        headerView.headerBackground.layer.shadowRadius = 10
        headerView.headerBackground.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
        headerView.headerBackground.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        headerView.headerBackground.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
        headerView.headerBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Background")
        headerView.headerBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        headerView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDropDown)))

        return headerView
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

@objc func handleDropDown() {
    print("Handle Drop Down")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
        return 0.0001
    } else {
        return 54
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
        return 10
    } else {
        return 20
    }
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return settings.count + 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return settings[section - 1].count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SettingTitleCell", for: indexPath) as! SettingsTitleTableViewCell

        cell.titleLabel.text = "Settings"

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SettingCell", for: indexPath) as! SettingTableViewCell

        cell.setSetting(setting: settings[indexPath.section - 1][indexPath.row])
        print("Index Path: \(indexPath.row) SettingCount: \(settings[indexPath.section - 1].count)")


        return cell
    }

}
```

That code produces this result:
[image: Current Result]

I would love some help on how to make this work the way I have shown in the design. Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Comment: Check Tim lib https://github.com/TimOliver/TORoundedTableView

Answer (score 0):

For collapse your header you can use this: https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section

Answer (score 0):

i used nested tableview to resolve it uibezierpath may be render incorrect layouts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).